# Compiling Twisted on Alpine Linux for Python 3.6

Tags: linux, twisted, python-3.6

I have the following Dockerfile, where I'm trying to compile Twisted with Python 3.6 as a target.

```
FROM alpine:3.5

RUN apk --update add \
      build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev python3-dev \
      libffi openssl ca-certificates python3
RUN apk add \
      py-pip \
      py-lxml \
      py-pillow
RUN \
    pip install --upgrade python-dateutil \
                          arrow \
                          pytz \
                          zope.interface \
                          https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/T/Twisted/Twisted-17.1.0.tar.bz2 \
                          jinja2
RUN \
    apk del build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev python3-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    rm -rf ~/.cache/ && \
    adduser -D -u 1001 noroot

USER noroot

CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

My problem is that I'm getting the following error, after Twisted has been copied:

```
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os
  -fomit-frame-pointer -g -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer
  -g -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/twisted/test/raiser.c
  -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/twisted/test/raiser.o 
  src/twisted/test/raiser.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or 
  directory
```

So it appears that something in Twisted is referring to the Python 2.7 headers, which I have not installed, as I'm not planning to target that version.

I can't find a special version of the Twisted download targeting Python 3.6.

I belong to those who stick to 2.7 mainly because of Twisted, and I was just trying to get my feet wet with 3.6, so keep that in mind when answering. I just wanted to check if my code runs on 3.6, what modifications I will have to make. But compiling Twisted is my first barrier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `py-pip` package, which you are installing, is for python 2.x.  Because of this, when you call `pip install ...` you are installing packages for python 2.x.

The `python3` packages provides a `pip3` command for python 3.  In general, `py-<something>` is for Python 2.x, and `py3-<something>` is for Python 3.x.  In other words:

```
FROM alpine:3.5

RUN apk --update add \
      build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev python3-dev \
      libffi openssl ca-certificates python3
RUN apk add \
      py3-lxml \
      py3-pillow
RUN \
    pip3 install --upgrade python-dateutil \
                          arrow \
                          pytz \
                          zope.interface \
                          https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/T/Twisted/Twisted-17.1.0.tar.bz2 \
                          jinja2
RUN \
    apk del build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev python3-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    rm -rf ~/.cache/ && \
    adduser -D -u 1001 noroot

USER noroot

CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```